# Impact of Stretching Tanh Activation Function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a network whose output corresponds to physical control parameters. The outputs must be in range [-1, 1] to respect the physics of the device. I am considering using $tanh$ activation function for this. I fear I will be prematurely clamping the performance of the network using a standard $tanh$ since any value above $\pm$ 10 is set to $\pm$ 1. If I were to stretch the domain of $tanh$ to say $tanh(.001*x)$, this would cast a wider net in terms of usable control parameters since $tanh(.001*1000) = .76$ for example, but how would this stretching by .001 affect the learning performance of the network?

Comment: What do you mean by "prematurely clamping the performance of the network?" The affine transformations of a neural network mean that the computation in the output layer looks like $\tanh(ax+b)$. In other words, the optimization process is trying to discover what recalling and shifting minimizes the loss. Introducing another scaling on top of that is redundant because linear functions are closed under composition.

Comment: @Sycorax The input to the tanh will range from [$-\infty$ $\infty$] until the network begins to converge to smaller values, so the output of tanh will be $\pm 1$ the vast majority of cases early in training. I am worried this prematurely clamps performance because $\pm 1$ are not the optimal control parameters, the optimal lies within [-1 1].

Comment: The purpose of data scaling and proper initialization is to keep the activations in the linear range early in training. If you've found that is not happening in your case, then that's where I'd start debugging.

Comment: @Sycorax Thanks!